# trying to get elastic search to run

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to get Elastic Search running in my Windows 7 environment, but being a complete NOOB in the Java world, I am not having success.

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Java and the latest JDK.  I navigate to my .\elasticsearch-0.18.6\bin directory and run elasticsearch.bat.  I get ...

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable must be set!
```

Can someone enlighten me on the proper Java setup I need on my machine so everything is there that elastic search needs?

Comment: Perhaps you could have added all this extra info to your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760696/running-elastic-search-as-a-windows-service) question? (or visa versa)

Comment: Well, I had it added to my original question, but then I realized I had asked two separate questions.  Since this site is a Q&A format I thought the moderators would appreciate me putting it as two separate questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://wso2.org/project/wsas/java/2.0/docs/setting-java-home.html) about setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable. This is just the first (of many) results from a Google search for "setting JAVA_HOME environment variable".

Comment: Thanks.  I actually did a Google search before I asked this question.  And I found that link as well.  However, rather than go through a bunch of manual steps (I figured JAVA_HOME wouldn't be the first thing missing), I was looking for an installer to create those settings.  That link indicates the JDK is required, so I installed it, but the environment variable wasn't set still so I figured I was still missing something.

Comment: Ok, have it figured out.  For anyone that has the same issue, install the latest bits for JVM (Java virtual machine), install the latest bits for the JDK (Java development kit), and you have to manually set the JAVA_HOME env variable as none of the installers take care of this.  My path is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02'.

Comment: for windows 8 i followed this tutorial: 

http://php-cms-job.blogspot.nl/2012/09/how-to-setting-javahome-variable-in.html

and after a reboot i got the elasticsearch server running locally

Answer (score 5):

```
         **How to Set Java_Home Environment**
```

-->Go to the drive where your windows is installed (generally it is c:\ drive) in "my computer".

-->Now go to "program files" folder and then go inside "java" folder( for a 64 bit OS, if the "JAVA" folder is not found, consider looking in "Program Files(x86)" folder). 
-->Look for a JAVA JDK installation folder. If you don't have it, then download java jdk and install the latest.

-->Copy the path name(e.g.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05) or just write it down on paper.

-->Now go to your desktop; right click on "my computer" icon; go to properties; go to "Advanced System Settings"; click on "Environment Variables"; click "new" in "System Variables".

-->Now, in "Variable Name" write "JAVA_HOME" and in the "Variable Value" area, put in the path of the JDK installation folder(e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05).

-->Click "OK" and again "OK" and "OK" again. Close any open windows( Not Necessarily).

```
                                      ALL DONE!!
```

Go ahead and run your ElasticSearch Batch file.

Comment: I got TO REBOOT Windows 7 after all this steps are done, until that JAVA_HOME variable was not seen to the system

Answer (score 1):

Set the JAVA_HOME Variable

Once you have the JDK installation path:

Right-click the My Computer icon on your desktop and select Properties.
Click the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button.
Under System Variables, click New.
Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
Click OK.
Click Apply Changes.
You might need to restart Windows.