# running Elastic Search as a Windows service

Tags: windows-services, elasticsearch

Is there a way to run Elastic Search as a Windows service?  It may not be possible, but I thought I would see.

Comment: Did you [check the installation docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html)? The wrapper described there [works on many OSes](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).

Comment: Checking here [Elastic service as window service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/elasticsearch-as-a-windows-service) also if any error find the document for Failed to [failed to start elasticsearch service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/failed-to-start-elasticsearch-service)

Answer (score 30):

As of 0.90.5+, support for running ElasticSearch as a Windows Service is officially included in the Windows distribution.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/0-90-5-released/

From the bin folder:

```
> service.bat
Usage: service.bat install|remove|start|stop|manager [SERVICE_ID]

> service install
Installing service      :  'elasticsearch-service-x64'
Using JAVA_HOME (64-bit):  c:jvmjdk1.7
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been installed.

> service start
The service 'elasticsearch-service-x64' has been started
```

Notice the latest version has changed bat name into `elasticsearch-service.bat`.

Comment: Funny. I've been putting this off, because I figured it would be complex. If I'd known it was this easy, I would have done this earlier. Took about all of 30 seconds from start to running as service.

Comment: Make sure JAVA_HOME is defined under `system variables`.

Comment: Checking here [Elastic service as window service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/elasticsearch-as-a-windows-service) also if any error find the document for Failed to [failed to start elasticsearch service](http://blogs.specialapps.in/failed-to-start-elasticsearch-service)

Answer (score 8):

Just made an install for windows service and setup tool for settings.

https://github.com/jdzurik/ESWindowsInstaller

Requires only Java and .net and works on windows server 64bit

Answer (score 6):

You can use this [binary install](http://ruilopes.com/elasticsearch-setup/) , works perfectly and you don't have to do anything in CLI.

Comment: It is a bit out-of-date with ElasticSearch at the moment

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this [installer](http://ruilopes.com/elasticsearch-setup/).
It is as easy as "next, next, next!"

Answer (score 3):

As of v0.90.5 functionality comes right out of the box (executing a batch file) - see [running as a service on windows](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service-win.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation.html).  That link describes using [Java Service Wrapper,](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) which can work on windows. :)

Comment: Note that the free community version does not support running ElasticSearch as a 64-bit process.

Answer (score 2):

All you need do is go to the folder where your ES is installed.

Run the commands

> service.bat
>
> service install
>
> service start

and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Elasticsearch msi installer with a customized ES config that fit your needs
or simply download the standard preconfigured installer:

https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-msi-installer/releases

Answer (score 0):

The time this question asked there wasn't inbuilt solution but now There is. Please check http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service-win.html

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch uses [procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to wrap the application as a windows service.

For Elasticsearch version starting *5.x*, the *.bat* file names are changed. 
To install as a Windows Service, we can use the following command:

```
C:\elasticsearch-5.0.0>.\bin\elasticsearch-service install
```

assuming your Elasticsearch package is located at `C:\elasticsearch-5.0.0`.

If we are using Elasticsearch on 64-bit Windows, we might end up with the following exception while doing the above:

> thread stack size not set; configure via C:\elasticsearch-5.0.0\config\jvm.options or ES_JAVA_OPTS

**[Reason](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18317):** The issue when running Elasticsearch as a service on Windows is that procrun requires min heap, max heap and thread stack size to be set.

**[Resolution](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/18324):** We could use **-Xss1m** (or what ever the space you want to be) in *jvm.options* file.

Open the *jvm.options* file in the *.\config* folder and enter **-Xss1m** after the lines

```
-Xms2g 
-Xmx2g
```

like below:

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
-Xss1m
```